# $domxpath->query - Check for title

Tags: php, dom, domparser

The query below is only searching for the first paragraph after the `<h2>` tag that contains "History" on a page of a website

```
            $paragraph = $domxpath->query('
                //h2[*[
                        contains(text(), "History")
                      ]
                    ]
                /following-sibling::p[
                        position() = 1 
                    ]'
            );
```

But I'd like somehow to check whether or not have any `<h2>` tag that contains history

```
foreach($paragraph as $node) {
                    $content= $node->nodeValue;                 
                }



                if(!isset($content)){
                    echo $content;
                }else{
                    echo "static content";
                }
```

this way it's not working

**update**

```
$html = file_get_contents( 'www.site.com' );    
                $document = new DOMDocument();              
                $document->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
                $domxpath = new DOMXPath($document);
                $paragraph = $domxpath->query('
                    //h2[*[
                            contains(text(), "History")
                          ]
                        ]
                    /following-sibling::p[
                            position() = 1 
                        ]'
                );
            }   


                foreach($paragraph as $node) {
                    $content= $node->nodeValue;

                }

                if(!isset($content)){
                    echo $content;
                }else{
                    echo "static content";
                }
```

but I do not know because when it does not have "history" it does not print the static content that is inside "else"

***code html:***

inside the div below has all the main content of the page

```
<div id="mw-content-text" lang="pt" dir="ltr" class="mw-content-ltr">
```

I would like to find the  that has "History"

```
<h2><span id="Hist.C3.B3ria"></span><span class="mw-headline" id="History">History</span><span class="mw-editsection"><span class="mw-editsection-bracket">[</span><a href="/w/index.php?title=Adamantina&amp;veaction=edit&amp;section=1" class="mw-editsection-visualeditor" title="Editar secção: History">editar</a><span class="mw-editsection-divider"> | </span><a href="/w/index.php?title=Adamantina&amp;action=edit&amp;section=1" title="Editar secção: History">editar código-fonte</a><span class="mw-editsection-bracket">]</span></span></h2>
```

between the opening `<h2>` tag of closing `</h2>` has a lot of code as it is possible to see above

Comment: The question is very unclear. Please provide an HTML example of what you have and what has to match.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'll improve this question.

Comment: @ishegg I updated my question please, see if it is clearer

Comment: It is, but it'd be much easier to help you if you post a excerpt of the HTML you're receiving and what you need to extract from it.

Comment: @ishegg updated again, please see

Comment: Is that the actual code? It's invalid HTML, you can't have the same `id` in more than one element.

Comment: @ishegg first `id` is `id="Hist.C3.B3ria"`

Comment: @Gislef I'm having a hard time understanding what you need. [Here](https://3v4l.org/Q3dOO) you can see a sample of an XPath query selecting span elements with "History" inside the text. Do you need something like that?

Comment: @ishegg I'm trying to somehow check if the site page has some `<h2>` that contains **History**, if it has history on the page, it only takes the first paragraph if it has no **History** in some `<h2>`  on the page  it prints a static content

Comment: `$paragraph = $domxpath->query('//h2/*[contains(text(), "History")]');` that will check for any "History" text inside `h2`

Comment: Yes, but I'm not able to create the if and else check. Even if there is no `History` on the page it always executes `if`

Comment: I see. Use `count($paragraph)` to get the number of results. `if (count($paragraph) > 0) { // History contained`

Comment: `if (!isset($content)) { echo $content; }` doesn't make sense.

Comment: @ishegg the result was the same

Comment: @Gislef check my answer and demo. Does that put you in the right path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this XPath query to get any `h2` elements with the string "History" contained anywhere inside it:

```
//h2/*[contains(text(), "History")]
```

Then, to check if the result is positive, count the results. If it's higher than 0, there are results:

```
$paragraph = $domxpath->query('//h2/*[contains(text(), "History")]');
if ($paragraph->length > 0) {
    echo "Results!";
}
else {
    echo "Not contained";
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/471Wt)

Comment: Thanks, but I think you have not understood my point yet. the content I want to print is just a paragraph. This paragraph will only be printed if there is "history"

Comment: It's not clear what *paragraph* you are referring to. In your own xpath you are doing the same thing, that xpath *selects next sibling paragraph when there is a `h2` that contains "history"* @Gislef

Comment: ok, imagine the following I have a huge list of pages if the page has histori this is printed in if if the page has no history prints else.

Comment: xpath only filters do not compare

Comment: Current answer does the same thing exactly. What things you have to compare to each other? @Gislef

Comment: @Gislef, I'm really confused. Maybe this will help me understand: can you point exactly how the answer differs from what you are expecting?

Comment: @ishegg I actually tried it in several ways I understand that the logic of your answer should work, but if the page has no history it should run the `else` but it does not work. I believe it is because it is an array object, I am now trying to check if this object is empty or not, because `count()` is not working the `else`

Comment: I am creating automatic postings in wordpress, if external page (in foreach list of pages) contains "history" the posting is being created, but if it has no history the posting is not being created, but should be created with the static content that is in `else`

Comment: You're totally right, sorry. I've updated the answer

Comment: @Gislef glad to have helped. Good luck.