# DOMXPath: Find all H2 and H3 headlines with a specific character

Tags: xml, dom, xpath, domdocument

I want to find every `<h2>` and `<h3>` tags which are a question.
So I need to check if the headline contains a question mark `?`.

At the moment my code looks like this:

```
$query = '//*[contains("h2 h3", name())]';
```

I saw in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3655588/1788961), that there is some kind of selector. But I'm not sure how to use something like this with my h2 and h3 selectors:

```
$query = '//*[contains(text(), '?')]';
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49100169/1788961) I found this:

```
$query = '//h2/*[contains(text(), "?")]';
```

But I get an error in my function.
You can see the function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75688697/1788961). I'm not sure if that's related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
$query = "//h2[contains(., '?')] | //h3[contains(., '?')]";
```